Java (AWT TrayIcon) and Linux
Newer Linux distributions switched to SNI for the management of the tray icon while Java (AWT) still uses xembed.
Is there a way to use SNI instead of xembed in Java?
xembed tray icons do not work on OS that uses SNI.

Please clarify what SNI is. By the context I guess it is not related to TLS SNI. Links would be useful too.

Which window managers support notification icons/tray icons?  I think that officially, AWT and Swing only support Gnome/Metacity/Mutter, though I could be wrong.

Looking at the release notes of Java 21.0.3 (and 17.0.11, and 11.0.23, and 8 update 411), I think you are out of luck with built-in support in Java. You'll need to look for third-party libraries to support this, I guess.
Specifically, the release notes say:

client-libs/java.awt
➜ AWT SystemTray API Is Not Supported on Most Linux Desktops (JDK-8322750)
The java.awt.SystemTray API is used for notifications in a desktop
taskbar and may include an icon representing an application. On Linux,
the Gnome desktop's own icon support in the taskbar has not worked
properly for several years due to a platform bug. This, in turn, has
affected the JDK's API, which relies upon that.
Therefore, in accordance with the existing Java SE specification,
java.awt.SystemTray.isSupported() will return false where ever the
JDK determines the platform bug is likely to be present.
The impact of this is likely to be limited since applications always
must check for that support anyway. Additionally, some distros have
not supported the SystemTray for several years unless the end-user
chooses to install non-bundled desktop extensions.

It does not address xembed vs SNI in any way, but I guess that might be the "platform bug" they talk about.
Alternatively, you'll need to report a bug to Oracle and/or the OpenJDK project to address this lack of support.
